# jQuery: Changing classes on click

Tags: jquery, css

I have a series of checkboxes that I want to make a little more mobile-friendly so I'm hiding the checkbox and using labels as buttons. What I want to do is give the user feedback by changing the color of the label from yellow to green when they tap, and then back to yellow when tapping again. I'm pulling my hair out trying to understand why what I'm using isn't working.

```
<div id="div">
    <label for="checkbox" id="label1" class="bg-warning text-center pointer" style="width:100px; padding:8px">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="checked1" style="display:none">test
        </label>
    </div>

    <label for="checkbox" id="label2" class="bg-warning text-center pointer" style="width:100px; padding:8px">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="checked2" style="display:none">test
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#div').on('click', function(e) {
            $('#div').each( function( index, element) {

                var el = $(element);

                if($(el).hasClass('bg-warning')) {
                    $(el).removeClass('bg-warning').addClass('bg-success');
                } else {
                    $(el).removeClass('bg-success').addClass('bg-warning');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: As I can see, it looks like you have more than one element sharing the same ID _div_, which is invalid.

Comment: Also, why are you looping through elements when you actually want to manipulate a single one, which is the one that has been tapped/clicked?

Comment: @MelanciaUK Because I'm a backend guy trying to learn jQuery :) I don't want to have to write a separate function for each checkbox, which is why I'm looping. Incorrectly, it appears.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/4ted9ayf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would give the divs unique IDs. Then you can set a common class to them (ie: div):

```
<div id="div1" class="div">
    <label for="checkbox" id="label1" class="bg-warning text-center pointer" style="width:100px; padding:8px">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="checked1" style="display:none" />test
    </label>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="div">
    <label for="checkbox" id="label2" class="bg-warning text-center pointer" style="width:100px; padding:8px">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="checked2" style="display:none" />test
    </label>
</div>
```

...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.div').on('click', function (e) {
        // Find the labels within the clicked div.
        var el = $('label', this);

        // Toggle their classes.
        // No loop needed, as the selector will bring all the elements
        // and apply the change to each one of them.            
        $(el).toggleClass('bg-warning').toggleClass('bg-success');
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/4ted9ayf/)

**UPDATE**

After our chat in the comments, I think you have two other options here.

Remember to use a `#` when setting the `for` attribute for the labels (ie: `for="#checkbox2"`).

First, you keep checking for clicks/taps in the div:

```
$(function () {    
    $('.div').on('click', function () {
        var label = $('label', this);
        var checkbox = $('input[type=checkbox]', this);

        label.toggleClass('bg-warning bg-success');

        // Checking the label class and deciding if we
        // need to check the checkbox.
        checkbox.prop('checked', label.hasClass('bg-success'));
    });

    $('label input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(e) {
        // As what's actually clicked is the label, let's
        // ignore the default behavior.
        e.preventDefault();

        // And transfer the click to the div itself.
        $(this).parents('.div').trigger('click');        
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/4ted9ayf/6/)

Second, you just handle the clicks/taps in the label (which I recommend):

```
$(function () {    
    $('label').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('bg-warning bg-success')
            .find('input[type=checkbox]')
            .prop('checked', $(this).hasClass('bg-success'));
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/4ted9ayf/9/)

Comment: Perfect. Simple, elegant and just what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: It is shorter : $(el).toggleClass('bg-warning bg-success');

Comment: @Football-Is-My-Life thanks for the improvement tip!

Comment: Spoke too soon. Clicking the label was not selecting the checkbox, as you had the same `for=""` on each label, so an ID wasn't being targeted. When updating the `for` to `checkbox1` and `checkbox2` it broke.

Comment: But I can't see this requirement in your question/code? I worked out just the class toggling...

Comment: You're right. I had a mistake in my code. Didn't see it because the checkboxes were invisible. I swapped my labels and IDs. :(

Comment: As I can see, the label is taking up the div space, which is normal, so when you click it, you're actually clicking the label, not the div. http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/4ted9ayf/3/

Comment: Yep, that's how it's supposed to work so the checkbox is checked when the form is submitted. Now I just need the div background to change colors.

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/4ted9ayf/6/ If it covers all your requirements, I can update the answer.

Comment: Perfect! Tested and works. Thanks for your patience and answering this twice. I just up-voted.